# How to enable a JAVADOC view in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, javadoc

When commenting a method in Eclipse, we have the possibility to select the method with the mouse and the Javadoc comment is popping up on the screen, which is very helpful to me.

That's what I am missing in Android Studio.

Can we do the same in Android Studio?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you type `/**` before the method declaration and press Enter, the javadoc comment block will be generated automatically.

```
 /**
     * 
     * @param 
     * @param 
     */
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the question. If you have that javadoc, then I could generate the javadoc. Thats clear. But I like to have a popup info of the javadoc comment, when going over the method with the mouse. In eclipse you get a yellow popup describing the method. You also will be able to jump thought the code with {@link references to other components in the code, which is very usefull. But I did not manage to do in Androidstudio. In Eclipse you have a Javadoc-View, which I am missing in Android Studio.

Comment: put the cursor over your method and press `ctrl+Q` show the method description, if you gave comment as I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So happy, that this is working... I have to get familiar with Android Studio....

Comment: what is Ctrl+Q for Mac? Or where can I find it in the menu?

Answer (score 9):

select the source item

menu > View > Quick Documentation

then Documentation view should appear on right-hand side.

Comment: This is the correct answer, such as "correct" happens to be But it doesn't provide nearly the functionality Eclipse provides with Javadocs.